# check if "show more" link has already been pressed python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have an issue where I am running a while loop and sometimes the webpage reloads and other times it does not. If reloaded, then I have to press on show more to scroll down. I tried to do this by writing the following function.

```
def Press_Show_more(driver):
    # time.sleep(1)
    # Press once on the "show more" which will lead to infinit loop
    path1 = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/studio-page/div/section/div/div/studio-video-results/video-results/div[3]/items-list/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"
    el = Check_If_element_exist_by_path(driver, path1)
    if 'WebElement' in str(type(el)):
        el.click()
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(
            Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    else:
        print('The show more element does not exist')
```

This did not work well for me in the while loop. Any help? Is this the best way to write the code?

```
def Check_If_element_exist_by_path(driver, path2):
    try:
        el = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path2)))
        return el
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"The non-existant path: {path2}")
```

Comment: What does "*this does not work well for me*" mean? Are there errors? If so, please post their [full text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Also, please post the contents of your `Check_If_element_exist_by_path()` function.

Comment: @MattDMo Just done so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to check for existence of an element is to use `.find_elements()` and check for an empty list.

```
def Press_Show_more(driver):
    path1 = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/studio-page/div/section/div/div/studio-video-results/video-results/div[3]/items-list/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, path1)))
    if len(el) > 0:
        el[0].click()
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(
            Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    else:
        print('The show more element does not exist')
```

Since the check has been significantly simplified, you don't need the `Check_If_element_exist_by_path()` method.

Comment: you need to give it some time to find "Show more" sometimes, it is not directly present.

Comment: @Anonymous You can just add a simple wait, if it's needed. I added a wait to the example code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented the `Check_If_element_exist_by_path` method here, but I think you can do that with `WebDriverWait` `ExpectedConditions` to wait for element presence of visibility. Also, I'd suggest to use method returning a list of web elements so in case of presence of the desired element the returned list will be non-empty and will be interpreted by `if` as a Boolean True, otherwise it will return an empty list and it will be interpreted as a Boolean false. Like the following:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
def Press_Show_more(driver):
    # time.sleep(1)
    # Press once on the "show more" which will lead to infinit loop
    path1 = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/studio-page/div/section/div/div/studio-video-results/video-results/div[3]/items-list/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"
    el = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, path1)))
    if el:
        actions.move_to_element(el[0]).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        el[0].click()
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(
            Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
    else:
        print('The show more element does not exist')
```

You will need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
```

Also, You should improve your locators

Comment: thank you for trying to help out. I am getting the following error 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' when 'show more' link is pressed

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You have to access the first element in the list. I've edited the answer

Comment: Still same error. If show more is pressed earlier I am getting "ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)"

Comment: Well, you did not show us the page you working on, but it makes sense :) You need to scroll to that element. Will add this code. However if there is some banner like accept cookies on the button you will have to close it too

Comment: I am working in MS Streams "https://web.microsoftstream.com/studio/videos"

Comment: Is it working now or there are any other / (same??!!) problems?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to thank @Prophet who was helpful to enable me to reach this solution

```
def Press_Show_more(driver):
    # Press once on the "show more" which will lead to infinit loop
    path1 = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/studio-page/div/section/div/div/studio-video-results/video-results/div[3]/items-list/div/div[2]/div[2]/button"
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, path1)))

    # Check if element is clickable
    try:
        el[0].click()
    except WebDriverException:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't think you want `presence` here... I think you would want `visible`. Presence just means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it's visible. If it's just present and you try to click on it, it will throw an exception.